# how to find user with in 20kms with the help of latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have to find all driver that are with in 20 kms based on passenger lat and log.

I have the following two table of driver and passenger.
 

passenger_id    passenger_name    passenger_lat    passenger_log



1                        David                       123.07                       55.03

2                        Sunil                       xyz.pq                        abc.7

And Driver table as

Driver_id      Driver_name              Driver_lat                  Driver_log



1                        Anil                       123.07                       55.03

2                        Jamis                       xyz.pq                        abc.7

Now I have input parameter of passenger_lat and passenger_log.based on that I have to return all Driver details that are with in 20 kms

```
 SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians(   lng ) - radians({$lng}) ) + sin( radians({$lat}) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM positions HAVING distance <= {$radius} ORDER BY distance ASC
```

plz provide the answer in php json and mysql

Comment: StackOverflow is not a software writing service. Please show your own effort and where you get stuck.

Comment: ya sir. use the following code like   SELECT
    *,
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lng` ) - radians({$lng}) ) + sin( radians({$lat}) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `positions`
HAVING distance <= {$radius}
ORDER BY distance ASC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class driver_service
{
    public function find_driver($data)
    {
        $driver_details=array();
        $driver_detail=array();
        $query="select driver_user_id,first_name,last_name,phone_no,cpf_no,driver_email_id,driver_image,current_latitude,current_longitude from driver_user";
        $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
       // $row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
         $driver=array();
         $dis=  $this->call_distance($data['user_latitude'],$data['user_longitude'],$row['current_latitude'],$row['current_longitude']);


         if($dis<=50)
         {
            $driver['driver_details']=$row; 
            $driver_detail[]=$driver;

         }
      }

      if(empty($driver_detail))
      {
          $driver_details['status']="2~there is no driver between 20 kms";

      }
      else{
      $driver_details['status']="1~success";    
      $driver_details['details']=$driver_detail;
      }
      echo json_encode($driver_details);
    } 
      public function call_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
      }


 }
 $driver_service=new driver_service();


if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'find_driver')
{
    $driver_service->find_driver($_REQUEST);

}
```

Comment: to test this code from localhost or server just use like localhost/filename.php?action=find_driver&user_latitude=some numeric value&user_longitude=some numeric value

Answer (score 0):

```
class distance
{
    public function all_user()
    {

        $query="select * from driver_user";
        $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
       // $row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
         $dis=  $this->call_distance(10,20,$row['current_latitude'],$row['current_longitude']);
        }
    }

  public function call_distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      return ($miles * 1.609344);


}
}
$distance=new distance();
$distance->all_user();
```